# Auto-generated code for "Using", "SQLConnection", "ReadItem", "ReadList" methods

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, bcs

I am beginner in SharePoint 2010 development. and doing following lab:

Module 6: Accessing external data with Business Connectivity Services in SharePoint 2010
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/ee513153 in Last video

I have developed the BCS model as in the lab. In the lab, the code for  "Using", "SQLConnection", "ReadItem", "ReadList" methods is auto-generated and the instructor just drag the code for respective method and Place it. He drag the code from "General" Category of ToolBox, where as, In my VS2010 development Environment, I don't find any Auto-generated code in "General" category of ToolBox for these methods

Now My question is:
How i can bring Auto-generated code for these methods?? Is there any feature in VS that i need to enable or need to make some Connection to Sql server??

I need explanation for this. If any Lab available for this, then it would be more helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not auto-generated code, but something the instructor has added to the toolbox prior to the presentation in order to give a more fluent presentation

Comment: Thanks! Thats i want to know what and how the instructor added to the toolbox ??

Comment: The instructor at some point wrote then entire code by hand. Then he opened the toolbox and pinned it. Then he just selected the text he want to use during the presentation and dragged it into the toolbox. Now everytime he opens a .cs file these items are in the toolbox.